# How to identify if a view contains a dialog in android?

Tags: android

I am displaying dialog box in android.Also these dialog object are not global but their scope is within the method were it is used.When i come from background to foreground i need to identify whether the dialog is displayed if yes dismiss it.I want to know how to identify if a view is displaying a dialog if yes then dismiss the dialog.
Following is my code:

```
public void reentersecuredpin()
    {
         final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
         dialog.setContentView(R.layout.successful_securepin_creation);
         dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
          dialog.setCancelable(true);

      Button btn_Ok;

      btn_Ok=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_Ok_successful_created_pin);
     TextView text1_success,text2_success;
     text1_success=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.text1_success);
     text2_success=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.text2_success);


     text1_success.setText("You have entered wrong Pin");
     text2_success.setText("Please re-enter your password again");


      btn_Ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
     {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    dialog.cancel();

                }
            });

         dialog.show();

    }
```

So when i come from background to foreground:

```
  @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {

        super.onResume();
        background_to_foreground_dialog();

    }
```

The background_to_foreground_dialog() displays another dialog.The problem what i am facing here is background_to_foreground_dialog() draws dialog on another dialog (when user had gone to background).How can i dismiss the previous dialog before drawing  background_to_foreground_dialog().

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `.isVisible()` method on the dialog in your `onPause()` and if that returns true dismiss your dialog. That way it is dismissed way before needing to dismiss it for the next dialog and when it comes to your `onResume()` you can just create your new dialog safely, without worrying about dismissing your other one.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(myDialog.isVisible()) {
          myDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: If dialog is global variable not need check visible dialog, you before doing its than running super onStop method. Mean your idea is separated ok?

Comment: @mr.boyfox That doesn't make sense. If you try to dismiss a dialog that is not visible, whether it is global or not, then you will get an error. And it doesn't really matter if its onStop or onPause, since like 90% of the time they will be called immediately after each other. All I am saying is that you must check for visibility before trying to dismissing it.

Comment: This is from Dialog.java: private void dismissDialog() {
        if (mDecor == null) {
            if (Config.LOGV) Log.v(LOG_TAG,
                    "[Dialog] dismiss: already dismissed, ignore");
            return;
        }
        if (!mShowing) {
            if (Config.LOGV) Log.v(LOG_TAG,
               "[Dialog] dismiss: not showing, ignore");
            return;
        }
        mWindowManager.removeView(mDecor);
        mDecor = null;
        mWindow.closeAllPanels();
        onStop();
        mShowing = false;
        sendDismissMessage(); }

Comment: `.dismiss()` and `.dismissDialog()` are two different functions....? Are they not?

Comment: you call dialog.dismiss() and in dialog class have dismiss method its called to their private dismissDialog(), see source code dialog.java, and try this(example on ProgressDialog):
    private static ProgressDialog dialog;
    Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);setContentView(R.layout.main);dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);dialog.setMessage("This is process dialog");dialog.show();}
    Override protected void onStop() {
     dialog.dismiss(); super.onStop();}

Comment: Run this code and will show progressDialog, and press home button, and more press home button and press app of list of running apps and you can see dismissed dialog activity.

Answer (score 0):

When your app go to background mode, activity called onStop method(see activityLifecycle documentation: [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)), here you make dismiss your dialog. Create global Dialog variable in the Activity, and use it is. For example:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: If the dialog is not visible (`.isVisible()` returns false) then this will throw a NullPointerException. You must first check `.isVisible()`, like my answer...

Answer (score 0):

To check that a dialog is displayed, you will have to declare your dialog as an attribute in your class so you can access it later and check if it's visible or not.

Comment: Can u please tell me how do i do that since i dont want to make my dialog as global variable.Is there some other way apart from doing that?

Comment: I don't think so, make your dialog as a global variable, that's not a problem.